# Typescript React SSR - Conumdrum

Tags: typescript, server-side-rendering

Going to keep it short.

Have backend in Typescript NodeJS
Have a frontend in Typescript in a separate directory.

Backend never imports anything from frontend.
Frontend never imports anything from backend.

Need to SSR my React application on the backend but the second i import my "Root Component" into my backend my Typescript backend passes my whole frontend through the backend typescript compiler, 'excludes' is ignored if you explicitly import anything from that directory so i can't use that but i essentially want to turn off typechecking for a whole directory in my backend to fix this issue.

How do i turn off type checking for a whole directory ? Or am i going to have to compile my frontend to javascript and then allowJS true just to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is this....

Instead of importing any files from my frontend using standard import syntax, which will force typescript to traverse those dependencies the solution was to import my frontend into my backend using....

```
const App = require("../../frontend/src/app");
const appSSR = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(App));
```